# what is the equivalent of matlab blockprop in opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv

What is the equivalent of blockproc in opencv?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html?refresh=true

I want to break the image in blocks of 3X3 and apply an average on each block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to do it manually

http://answers.opencv.org/question/33258/how-to-cut-an-image-in-small-images-with-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

When using python binding we can do the following

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np



mat = cv2.imread('x.jpg')

rows, cols, x = mat.shape 
rows, cols = 3*(rows/3),  3*(cols/3) 
reshaped = mat[:rows,:cols].reshape(rows//3, 3, cols//3, 3,3) 
mat1 = reshaped.sum(axis=(1, 3)) / 9

cv2.imwrite('y.jpg', mat1.astype(np.uint8))
```